# Keep WPF DataGrid sorting when backing collection is replaced

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is there a method to easily preserve DataGrid sorting when the backing collection is replaced with a new collection (as opposed to updating the existing collection)?  I have an application where the user is allowed to select a number of devices and a corresponding collection is updated with a union or intersection of a collection property on those devices.  It's easy enough to do the union/intersection, but when I replace the property that my DataGrid ItemsSource is bound to, the sorting is lost and I would like to preserve it.

I've tried implementing a CollectionView but that appears to require that I create a new CollectionView each time that backing collection is replaced, and doesn't seem very elegant.  Is there a better solution?

Comment: What database are you using?  Not all databases return data in order that items are entered.  For example SQL Server is multi-threaded so results do not comeback in same order every time.  If order is important than you should use an Order By in the query to get results in proper order.

Comment: The database is irrelevant to this question.  I have the data set and I'm letting the DataGrid do the sorting as the user desires.  I'm just trying to preserve that sorting when the dataset is replaced with an entirely different backing collection.

Comment: Your only chance is to reuse the original source collection. If it is a ObservableCollection you can simply clear or remove the required items and then add/insert the new ones.

Comment: Thanks @BionicCode.  That what I've done for now but it seemed like there should be a better way.

Comment: Have you tried transfering the SortDescription items from CollectionView.SortDescriptions of your old collection to the new one by getting [CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Data_CollectionViewSource_GetDefaultView_System_Object_) of your new collection?

Comment: Why not do the sorting in the query to the database?

Comment: @jdweng There is no database to query, and even if there was, why should I re-query the database when the user decides to change the sorting?

Comment: Where is data coming from if not a database?  Is it a file? A file is a database! Is it a webpage?  A webpage is a html file which is a database.  If you want same order every time than you have to bind the grid to the database and database has to be in the order.  Changing the database will give order of new database.